# Double.MinValue, MaxValue Bad Compile Time Constant -- mscorlib

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, double

I've been looking and and trying to learn from the source code of the mscorlib library (4.0) using dotPeek's Export To Project's functionality, and when I try to build it, it fails because of Double's MinValue and MaxValue being 'Bad Compile Time Constants'.

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public const double MinValue = -1.79769313486232E+308; // Bad compile time constant

[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public const double MaxValue = 1.79769313486232E+308; // Bad compile time constant
```

What am I missing here exactly?  Would exporting the compiler generated code resolve this issue, or is there some sort of behind the scenes operation that is resolving this?

Note:  Using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate to build, I have 2012, and 2010 versions of Visual Studio as well (love college), unsure if the compiler that I use will change this issue or not.

Comment: IIRC, the primitive types (`double`, `int`, etc) shouldn't be decompiled/recompiled. They're actually specially compiled types that can't be directly recompiled as-is as described by the decompiled IL.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Any sources about that?

Comment: @Chris Sinclair Haven't even looked at the Intermediate Language, I figured there was something I overlooked, thanks.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Sorry, I can't find a source. I was directed to it once on a SO question but my googling skills have failed me.

Comment: Your decompiler is wanky, use the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the application that generated the constants for you generated the wrong numbers. The correct numbers are:

```
    public const double MinValue = -1.7976931348623157E+308;
```

and

```
    public const double MaxValue = 1.7976931348623157E+308;
```

The code that was generated rounds the last 4 digits from 3157 to 32(00), which exceeds the value of a double.